# How to match the data with new line.?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I tried to match the data with newline and some other data but its not working.
My perl code

```
open(data,"filename");
@file = <data>;
@get = grep{m/^\>.*\n.*/} @file; 
print "$get[1]";
```

My file like this

```
>1AA7
LSLLSEVESFVLSVVPSGPLKAEVAQKLEEVFAGKQSELEVLLEFLKSKPVLSPLSKGVLGFVFSLSVPSEKGLQKKKFVQQALQGQGEPQQLEKAVKLFK

>1ABV
SEFVSVAKPFAKAAFEFAVEKQSVEKFQELLAFAAEVSKQEQLAELLSGALAPESLAESFVAVCGEQLEEQGQQLVKVLAEQGKLQALPEVLEQFVKLKAVSEASAEVEVVSAAALSEQQLAKVSAALEKKLSK

>1AEP
AAGKVQVAEAVQQLQKSVVQAAKELKESLGLPSPEEALQLLSEQAQAFKSKVAEVSSSLKQEAEKKQGSVAEQLQAFAKQLQQSVKEAASSLQLQEQLQSLQSALSQVGKQFQEVASKSQASAQEAFAPVQSALQEAAEKSKEAAAQLQQSVQSAVQKPAQ
```

In this program gives the output only `>1ABV` not working the `\n` and another charactor in my code. But I expect the output from this code

```
>1ABV
SEFVSVAKPFAKAAFEFAVEKQSVEKFQELLAFAAEVSKQEQLAELLSGALAPESLAESFVAVCGEQLEEQGQQLVKVLAEQGKLQALPEVLEQFVKLKAVSEASAEVEVVSAAALSEQQLAKVSAALEKKLSK
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want paragraph mode for reading.

You can obtain that by modifying the [`$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '';  # Paragraph mode

my @data = <DATA>;

print $data[0];

__DATA__
>1AA7
LSLLSEVESFVLSVVPSGPLKAEVAQKLEEVFAGKQSELEVLLEFLKSKPVLSPLSKGVLGFVFSLSVPSEKGLQKKKFVQQALQGQGEPQQLEKAVKLFK

>1ABV
SEFVSVAKPFAKAAFEFAVEKQSVEKFQELLAFAAEVSKQEQLAELLSGALAPESLAESFVAVCGEQLEEQGQQLVKVLAEQGKLQALPEVLEQFVKLKAVSEASAEVEVVSAAALSEQQLAKVSAALEKKLSK

>1AEP
AAGKVQVAEAVQQLQKSVVQAAKELKESLGLPSPEEALQLLSEQAQAFKSKVAEVSSSLKQEAEKKQGSVAEQLQAFAKQLQQSVKEAASSLQLQEQLQSLQSALSQVGKQFQEVASKSQASAQEAFAPVQSALQEAAEKSKEAAAQLQQSVQSAVQKPA
```

Outputs:

```
>1AA7
LSLLSEVESFVLSVVPSGPLKAEVAQKLEEVFAGKQSELEVLLEFLKSKPVLSPLSKGVLGFVFSLSVPSEKGLQKKKFVQQALQGQGEPQQLEKAVKLFK
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/3mwlat)</kbd>

Note: array indexes start from 0 in Perl.

Comment: @Miler: Thank you. please explain this code `local $/ = '';`

Comment: Read the [linked to docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR).  The first paragraph explains.

Comment: @Miller: It is not possible using regular expersion.

Comment: @Hussain: your regex is not your problem; your problem is that you only use the regex on one line at a time.  Use paragraph mode and continue to use your regex.

Comment: @ysth: Thank you. I get a idea about it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read content separated by multiple newlines into an array,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @get = do {
  open(my $data, "<", "filename");
  local $/ = "";
  <$data>;
};
```

From [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR)

> *$/*
>
> [...] Setting to "" will treat two or more consecutive empty lines as a single empty line.